# Ajax timed reload of php page and populating data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax script on index.html to retrieve content from content.php every 60 seconds and fill it into corresponding spans:

```
repeatAjax();


function repeatAjax(){
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'content.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(resp) {
                    jQuery('div.out1').html(resp[0]);
                    jQuery('div.out2').html(resp[1]);
                    jQuery('div.out3').html(resp[2]);

          },
          complete: function() {
                setTimeout(repeatAjax,60000); //After completion of request, time to redo it after a second
             }
        });
}
```

and the content.php:

```
$volume1=1;

$speed1=2;


$progress1=3;


$data1=array($progress1,$speed1,$volume1);


echo json_encode($data1);
```

and my html looks like:

```
<div class="out1">
<span>test</span><br />
</div>
<div class="out2">
<span>test</span><br />
</div>
<div class="out3">
<span>test</span><br />
</div>
```

For some reason ajax is not working and text doesn't get changed in target spans. I know that array $data1 in content.php is true, so it gets stuck somewhere on ajax part. Please help!

Here I tried to setup [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dys31yt8/), not sure if this is correct, never set up it for ajax before.

Comment: I do load jquery before ajax script too

Comment: you shuold use JSON.parse in the complete function.
resp = JSON.parse(resp);

if this not helping - can you please console.log your resp and paste it here.

Comment: Check what your browser js and network consoles, they should contain some errors or at least some indication of why it is not working.

Comment: @IdanMagled when `dataType` is set to `json` jQuery will return parsed object already

Comment: @Acidon inspect request in browser console network tab to see if it succeeds, and what is returned.

Comment: @charlietfl `content.php
/LocalSite
POST 200
OK`, and same request every 60 seconds so this part seems to work

Comment: I've also tried to setup jsfiddle above, not sure if this is correct, never set up it for ajax before.

Comment: can you just  console.log(resp) like this:

 success: function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    jQuery('div.out1').html(resp[0]);
                    jQuery('div.out2').html(resp[1]);
                    jQuery('div.out3').html(resp[2]);

          },

and copy paste here what is writing in the console tab?

Comment: @IdanMagled I tried that before, and just tried again - it doesnt output anything on browser screen, no errors either

Comment: you need to open the developers tools by clicking f12 key on the keyboard. 
then move to the console tab and refresh.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I've looked there before, I don't see anything related to resp, only some error `Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'state' of null`